# Error finding largest randomly generated double in ArrayList Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, random, double

I'm trying to get a program to work where I generate 1,000,000 random numbers between 0 and 1 and then find and print the largest number.

I've got the generator to work and managed to insert each double generated into an ArrayList but I cannot seem to figure out how to find the largest number in the list. At the moment the current code throws the error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException".

This is all probably due to me being new to the ArrayList and not being fluent with its commands and how it works but I would really appreciate some help on what I'm doing wrong here as I've been stuck for a  while.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class milran {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        ArrayList<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 1; i<=1000000; i++){
            double randomValue = 0.0+(1.0-0.0)*r.nextDouble();
            myList.add(randomValue);

        }
        double max = myList.get(1);
        for (int z=2; z<=myList.size(); z++){
            double test = myList.get(z);
            if (test>max){
                max = test;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all take a look at the docs for [java.util.Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) and [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).
Secondly, the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is being triggered by this...

```
for (int z=2; z<=myList.size(); z++){
        double test = myList.get(z);
        ...
}
```

This is because array indexing starts at 0, therefore the last element is myList.size() **- 1**. In other words, when `z = myList.size()`, it is out of bounds.

Also, in your first `for` loop, you are using `i = 1; 1 <= 1000000`. It makes much more sense to use `i = 0; i < 1000000` as you can use `i` to touch each element in an array (or list).

```
for( i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
{
    // do something with myArray[i]
}
```

---

Here's what I would do after the values have been inserted...

1. **Sort the array:** `Collections.sort(myList);`
2. **Retrieve the last element:** `System.out.println( myList.get( myList.size() - 1 ) );`

...and that's it.

If you need to implement the actual sort yourself then i'd consider using a primitive double array (`double[]`) rather than a Collection.

Otherwise, if you are using a collection, you can use a foreach loop.

```
for( Double d : myList ) // for each Double 'd' in myList
{
    // do something with d
}
```

N.B. Another potential issue with this line in the second loop

```
double test = myList.get(z);
```

This automatic conversion from `Double` (object) to `double` (primitive) is called [unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). There *will* be a performance cost, especially when repeated a million times. In the first loop you are converting the other way (autoboxing) – also a million times.

Comment: Why do you recommend sorting, rather than just scanning the list once to find the largest element?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan – For reuse purposes. Unsorted arrays tend to slow things down over time. What happens when you need the 2nd largest element? Then the third? Keep scanning the array? Thats O(n^2). You could just use Collections.sort(List<T> list)

Comment: ^^implemented with variations of merge sort (timsort) which is O(nlogn) and a best case of O(n)

Comment: ...and in this particular case, if you only need to traverse the array once, I'd be asking myself why I was storing all the values, placing them in a list the size of a million Doubles (+ the size of ArrayList class itself)

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` start count its elements from `0`. You need to replace `myList.get(1)` to `myList.get(0)`, `int z=2` to `int z=1` and `z<=myList.size()` to `z<myList.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `for (int z=2; z<=myList.size(); z++) {` is wrong. It should be `for (int z=1; z<myList.size(); z++) {`.

This is because arrays and lists are 0 based, so a list of size 2 has 2 elements - index 0 and index 1. Currently you try to index into the element number equal to the size, which does not exist.

Along the same line, `myList.get(1);` should be `myList.get(0);`.

This is unrelated to your problem, but this line `0.0+(1.0-0.0)*r.nextDouble();` can be much more easily written as `r.nextDouble();`. I'm not sure what you were trying to do by doing 0 + 1 - 0.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you have an error in your for-loop condition that causes the index to go out-of-bounds.

One way that you can avoid this in the future is by using Java's for-each loop syntax instead of trying to manage the index yourself.

```
for (Double test : myList) {
    if (test>max){
        max = test;
    }
}
```

This syntax makes your intent much clearer than the traditional indexed `for` syntax and removes a point of potential error (managing the index and the bounds of the list) from your hands.